# Is there a way to change Font Sizes in the entire app through a stepper in Xamarin for both Android and iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So far I have the code setup like this:

```
Label h1 = new Label
        {
            Text = "Text Size",
            Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["headerStyle"],
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
        };

        Stepper stepper = new Stepper
        {
            Maximum = 40,
            Increment = 10,
        };

        Label textBody = new Label
        {
            Text = "Sample Text" + "\n" + "Lorem ipsum",
            Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["labelStyle"],
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
        };

        stepper.ValueChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            //TODO: Change this line to allow font size change.
            textBody.FontSize = stepper.Value;
        };
```

I need to change the FontSize through the line above in the whole app.

Comment: You need to create a resource dictionary

Comment: You want to change the fontsize of all albel in your app?